# How to elegantly put all enums into a std::set

Tags: c++, enums, stdset

I have an enum and I want to put them all in the set( and then remove some with set_intersection algorithm, but that is offtopic).
 All works great except Im stuck on step 1. :)

If I have(real class has enum with higher cardinality)

```
class MyClass
{
enum Color{red, green , blue}
};
```

How would I init a `std::set<MyClass::Color>`  to contain all enums.
I can obviously manually insert them one by one, do a for loop with casting since they are consecutive and start from 0 (I think that is required if I dont use  = in enum definition), but Im looking for a more elegant  way.

EDIT: I prefer C++03 solution if possible because current instance of problem requires it, but if not C++11 is good to know too.

Comment: if they are consecutive and starting from zero, you can add `total` as last enum's element, which value becomes equal to number of values =)

Comment: Good remark from @kassak `total` or `colors_count` as a last element of enum is very useful in many cases

Comment: @kassak I know of that trick, but it depends on CAPS LOCK comments preventing ppl to go and define int value of each enum. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an option:

```
#define COLORS {red, green , blue}
enum Color COLORS;
static std::set<Color> color_set() {
    return COLORS;
}
#undef COLORS
```

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Yes, initializer lists.

Comment: I edited Q to say i prefer 03 if possible, but if this is the only nice way to do it Ill accept your A. Sorry for not mentioning it in initial Q. :)

Comment: If you don't have initializer lists, you can do something like `Color colors[] = COLORS; return std::set<Color>(colors, colors + sizeof(colors) / sizeof(*colors));`

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl in 03 you could define without braces, and then pass comma separated list to boost assign

Comment: @SteveJessop ah, good old array initialization of STL containers :) tnx

Comment: @SteveJessop I'd add `static` before `Color colors[] = COLORS;`

Comment: @borisbn: if you like. I don't think it makes much difference: each call to this function constructs a `set`, so I don't really care whether or not it also initializes the array every time :-)

Comment: In my view any solution that uses `#define` is by definition inelegant. I would view this code has substantially less elegant than the loop option rejected by the OP.

Comment: @JackAidley: `#define` are oftentimes inelegant because they can be really hard to read. But in this case, I think it's actually really easy to read, and the resulting code is very short and concise.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `std::bitset< total_colors >`. That is a more appropriate data structure for a set over a finite space. Each color maps to a Boolean value, representing whether or not it is part of the set. You can initialize it to all `true`'s using `my_bitset.set()`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd use a loop, and just cast the things as I go.

However, if you're dead set against casts you could define operators on the enum so you can iterate over them using `++`. That way you can loop without casting.

Comment: Well, the definition of `++` would contain the cast.

Comment: Yes, but the loop wouldn't. You'd be dealing with an interface that hides the grissly details.