# Defining operators for enums nested within a class

Tags: c++, enums, operator-overloading

Say I have this:

```
class Example {
    enum class E { elem1, elem2 };
    E& operator++(E& e) {
        // do things
    }
};
```

Seems to make perfect sense and I even see it used in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451382/implementation-of-operators-for-enum-class), but the compiler tells me that the parameters can only be either empty or an int.

This makes sense within a normal class, but exactly what am I supposed to operate on when I don't have a `this` value?

Comment: The question is not totally clear, can you reproduce live example using [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) or  [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox) and produce a live example.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour http://ideone.com/tEmYxD It's basically just exactly what's in the question, but with the relevant error message.

Comment: That is just incorrect, the operator is for class Example, if you take away the wrapping class then [it works fine](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/cTf764hJC2suBsaC). Also returning a reference to a local variable is undefined behavior.

Comment: I know that it works fine if one takes away the wrapping class, but I'm trying to define an operator for an enum inside that class--I don't get why it can't be done. Fixed the local variable thing, thanks.

Comment: Define it outside the class [like so](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BT6p0V9iwRHFvtna)

Comment: I see now, seems kind of roundabout but thanks. Can you make your comment an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator you defined inside the class applies to the class `Example` and therefore having an argument and return type of `E&` is incorrect and the compiler tells you so.

The standard tell us that:

> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function[...]

it can't be a non-static member function of `E` therefore it has to be a non-member function.

You can define the operator outside of `Example` as follows:

```
Example::E& operator++(Example::E& e) {
    // modify e
    return e ;
}
```

Comment: What if `E` is a private enum (as in the original question), used solely within the `Example` class? Does that mean that C++ doesn't have a way how to define an operator in such case? (that would be quite surprising...)

Answer (score 0):

As @Shafik answered you can declare operator for an enum that is declared inside of class only as non-member function, like here:

```
class Example 
{
public:
    enum class Element
    { 
        Element1, 
        Element2
    };
};

Example::Element operator++(Example::Element element)
{
     // do things
}
```

There is a nice [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451382/implementation-of-operators-for-enum-class) regarding implementation of increment operator for enums. Hope it will help you :)